# How do I delete old rows based on table size and available free space?

Tags: postgresql

I have continuous inserts into my table, and want to automatically delete the oldest rows to maintain a constant table size (meaning the size of the table on the hard drive). I was able to do this in mysql using:

```
SELECT DATA_LENGTH,DATA_FREE FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'table';
```

Using these values and the free space on the drive, I can issue delete statements, and the table size will not grow.

How can I do this in postgresql? I could only find the table size:

```
SELECT pg_total_relation_size('table_name');
```

Is there a way to find the free space in the table, or is there a better solution to keep the table at a fixed size?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a start for table sizes

```
SELECT relname, relpages * 8192 "Size_In_Bytes" 
FROM pg_class c
JOIN information_schema.tables t 
    ON c.relname = t.table_name 
WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
ORDER BY  relpages * 8192 DESC
```

I am somewhat curious about the requirement to keep the DB at a certain size. Do you archive the data elsewhere? If not, why keep it at all? Why not make it a time-based retention policy than a size-based retention policy?

Comment: Thanks, but I can already find the table size. My data is disposable, only needs to be around for a few days, and I have a 15GB disk.

Comment: @atlau My apologies, I completely misread that part of the question. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/storage-fsm.html. I've also found an extension called `pg_freespacemap` that may be helpful for you.

Comment: I found an extension called pgstattuple which seems to be what I was looking for: SELECT free_space FROM pgstattuple('table'); Thanks!